# Is there any reusable D3 chart code to draw a Bar Chart with negative values, one on the top of another?

Tags: d3.js

[image: Click to open the image of my chart]
I am trying to create a bar chart as shown in the picture, till now I have tried using this code " http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2368837". Is there any reusable code similar to the one I am trying to create?
*Note- I am very newbie in D3.js

Comment: From the image you have shown, it seems that there is only **ONE** the bar chart in each row, but the horizontal positioning of the bar chart is determined by your data, `13`, `20` and `6080` relative to the min and max of the bar chart, am I right?

Comment: @LaurentY 13,20,6080 is not related to graph.Consider it as static data only [Just for this case]. My dataset contains percentage of male and female [Blue male, Red Female]. and FTSE for male and female.

Comment: @paradite previous comment from is for you,not for me

Comment: so are the numbers 13, 20 and 6080 related to your question at all? It seems to be related but I can't be sure.

Comment: @paradite No these are not related to graph

Comment: So as far as I understand you want the image inplace of y axis in the mike bostock's example.

Comment: @SiddP no, I am trying to create two graphs. one with positive values and another with negative values.  I have created that. The one shown in RED AND Blue horizontal bar graph. I am not able to create the another graph over the top of it, to show FTSE SCALE

Comment: Can you create a fiddle of what you have tried so that it would be easy for us to take on.

Comment: I still don't understand why you need two graph for both red and blue part. The total length of each row is the CONSTANT (100%). You are basically setting the start position of each row, 79%, 88%, 71%, then dissecting that row into two colors at the 0%.

Comment: @paradite http://plnkr.co/edit/7AqWehtRWw8TBDRnzAXC?p=preview

Comment: okay based on your data on `plunker`, the total width is not always 100, but the example you showed in the image indicates that it is constant, so what is exact situation you have?

Comment: i have just created one small sample on Plunker

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://classee.project.cwi.nl/component/barplot

It features an open source component of a Classee Project (a collaboration between CWI and University of Amsterdam (UvA), funded by the Amsterdam Data Science institute (ADS)).

For every x-sample, it has 2 +ve values(FP, TP) and 2 -ve values(FN, TN). You shall remove any one of the +ve and one -ve value ( I mean changing the corresponding code) and you're done.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: thanks typhon, its not exactly what am searching for, but its helping me in creating my graph a bit